# Doesn’t the very existence of Federation timeships and officers violate the Temporal Prime Directive?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek (multiple Series) you meet Time traveling Starfleet Personnel, that are tasked with repairing the timeline from Temporal incursions/changes so that the timeline isn't contaminated. they even have whole Class Ships for this purpose (The Wells-class and Aeon-type)

Doesn't the very existence of the Temporal Prime Directive and "Time Traveling Repairmen" that go around fixing the timeline violate itself by even existing and doing what they do?

The Temporal Prime Directive and "The Temporal Repairmen" also seem to be work in violation to each other.

Comment: Your premise would depend on the wording of the Temporal Prime Directive, which I suspect we never get.

Comment: While not film / TV canon - the books in the "Department of Temporal Investigations" get into some detail as to how the department works and why and follow Mulder and Scully - er, I mean...Dulmer and Lucsly

Answer (score 9):

The "enforcers" of the Temporal Prime Directive have a perspective on the "correct" timeline (presumably one which is "pristine" - unfolded without any influence due to time travel, either intentional or unintentional). If time travel occurred and influenced the timeline, the "repairmen" are tasked with nullifying the effects. Yes, they themselves are influencing the timeline, but only as needed to make it as if the original alteration never occurred.

The philosophy is no different to that of the "Prime Directive" as originally presented in TOS. Even though Kirk and his crew interfered with more than one less developed culture (destroying Landru and Val, interpreting the "e plebnista", arming the "Hill People"), Kirk deemed it necessary and appropriate to "undo the contamination" on Sigma Iotia II previously caused by the Horizon ("A Piece of the Action).

It's why they call it the "Temporal Prime Directive" - same general philosophy, just applied in a different context.